# Animate change of rootViewController to SplitViewController?

Tags: ios, animation

I have a project that starts off with a tableView, however when the user taps the Setup button, I want to animate the change to a splitViewController.

I can easily change the rootViewController, however the animation isn't as advertised:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SetupViewController"];
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    app.window.rootViewController = controller;

                }
                completion:nil];
```

Is there a way I can animate this change of rootViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a little hackie, but try setting the root before the animation and back again, so the new `ViewController` gets the right size when you start the animation:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SetupViewController"];
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIViewController *currentController = app.window.rootViewController;
app.window.rootViewController = controller;
app.window.rootViewController = currentController;

[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view.window
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    app.window.rootViewController = controller;

                }
                completion:nil];
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: While it does get rid of the expand from middle animation, it is now just instantaneous as if I had done no animation at all. :( Perhaps there is no way to animate this kind of transition.

Comment: Is your destination controller a splitViewController?

Comment: yes, and one more difference I didn't notice, try it with `self.navigationController.view.window`. I've updated my answer also